# Liberating email addresses from outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

I have outlook 2007, and I recently sent an email with a BCC of about 75 addresses.  I would like to copy and paste this BCC list into a spreadsheet to keep track of the names AND email addresses of the people I contacted.

The problem is, when I copy the BCC field from outlook, it only copies the names in the list, NOT the email addresses.

How do I liberate these email addresses from outlook's cold, dead hands?  Is there any way to force outlook to copy the email addresses, rather than the names? Does this useless feature have any purpose, other than frustrating users and preventing them from using competing email services?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [NK2Edit](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html) to solve this problem.  I had to manually select the emails I wanted, which was a little tedious, but it allowed me to copy the names and email addresses as a tab-delimited file.

I'm still curious why outlook has this strange behavior, and it there's a good way to stop it.